# Why frame->pts increases by 20, rather than by 1?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding

Following the exmaples of ffmpeg: decoding_encoding.c and  filtering_video.c, I process one video file taken by iPhone. The video file: .mov, video dimensions; 480x272, video Codec: H.264/AVC, 30 frames per second, bitrate: 605 kbps.

I first extract each frame, which is YUV.
I convert YUV to RGB24, and process the RGB24, then write the RGB24 to a .ppm file. It shows the .ppm file is correct.

Then I plan to encode processed RGB24 frames to a video file.
Since MPEG does not support RGB24 picture format, I used AV_CODEC_ID_HUFFYUV.
But the output video file (showing 18.5 MB) does not play. Movie Player on Ubuntu claims an error: Could not determine type of stream.
I also tried it on VCL. It simply does not work, without any error information.

My second questions is:
For each extracted fram from the input video file, I get its pts as follows according to filtering_video.c:

> `frame->pts = av_frame_get_best_effort_timestamp(frame);`

I print out each frame's pts, and find that it increases by 20, like below:

```
pFrameRGB_count: 0,  frame->pts: 0
pFrameRGB_count: 1,  frame->pts: 20
pFrameRGB_count: 2,  frame->pts: 40
pFrameRGB_count: 3,  frame->pts: 60
```

Where frame is the extracted frame from the input video, and pFrameRGB_count is the count for processed frame in RGB24 form.

Why are they wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

H.264 videos use a `90 kHz clock` for encoding `timestamps`. Since your video is `30 fps`, the PTS delta between 2 successive frames should be `3000` instead of `20`.

A value of 20 indicates one or both of the following:

- Your encoding clock (i.e. sampling rate) is configured incorrectly (to 600 Hz) for the given frame rate of 30 fps
- Your frames per second is configured incorrectly (to 4500fps).

The general formula to calculate PTS delta is:

```
PTS delta = (1/fps) * Encoder sampling rate
```

Answer (score 0):

I debug to get codec context of the input video file, dec_ctx->time_base.den = 1200;
I know the fps, 30, by right-click the input video file to check its properties (Ubuntu 12.04)
So it seems the frame duration should be 1200/30 = 40 base units.
But it is 20 by using frame->pts = av_frame_get_best_effort_timestamp(frame);

the read packet of the input video has the duration = 20.

I found dec_ctx->ticks_per_frame = 2. I guess ticks_per_frame makes 40 to 20.
Maybe there is some inner formula, like: frame duration in base unit = frame duration x ticks_per_frame (but it seems it is different from what is said in the ffmpeg document, such as time_base is equal to 1/frame rate.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I find the answer.
Due to lack of detailed documentation of ffmpeg, users might be mislead.
I find that, to get correct pts, one should always use:
video_st->time_base
NOT video_st->codec->time_base

(a) Absolute time of a frame:

packet->dts * (1/video_st->time_base.den)

(b) Absolute time between the frame and its next frame:

frame->repeat_pict * (1/video_st->time_base.den)